# What's a word for "weird but somewhat normal?" Or odd/disgusting instead of weird

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For example:

- being attracted to a cousin.
- picking your nose and eating it.
- liking the smell of your own flatulence.

etc.

Comment: Can you please explain further? What do you mean by "somewhat normal"? It is actually not normal because it is deviating from what is normal. (thus, _abnormal_ is a possible answer). Though _weird_ and _odd_ fit too, why do you think they don't fit?

Comment: @ermanen Um, perhaps a better way to phrase it would be something that's taboo to discuss casually but occurs frequently enough that it's socially acceptable.

Comment: There's nothing "somewhat normal" about liking one's snot or fart smells....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps *unorthodox* could work. If by 'weird but somewhat normal' you mean something that is indeed weird/odd but still happens often. Like the examples you mentioned above.

> Though incest is frowned upon and considered unorthodox, there are still some cultures in which it's accepted.

Answer (score 2):

[Eccentric](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/eccentric) seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

like ermanen's comment, odd, weird, and abnormal fit. There are also several others, such as describing it as an idiosyncrasy. This, however, is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: _Idiosyncratic_ is the adjective form.

Comment: You would call someone "odd" or simply "weird", if they said they liked eating their snot? And in any case, those two words are already in the question title.